# How to use both JWPlayer 6 and JWPlayer 7 in same project?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, express, jwplayer

I need to use both JWPlayer 6 and JWPlayer 7 in my expressJS, AngularJS project. 
Normally each of them works fine individually.

I include them separately in index.html

```
   <script src="/javascripts/jwplayer6.js"></script>
OR
   <script src="javascripts/jwplayer7.js" ></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">jwplayer.key="xxxx"; </script>
```

I have player.html and player.controler.js on angular side and I keep JWPlayer configuration object in player.controler.js

```
                    $scope.options = {

                        width: "400px",
                        aspectratio: "16:9",
                        autostart: true,
                        androidhls: true,
                        image: '/images/04212a71.abcd.png'

                    };

                    $scope.file = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url);
```

In player.html file, I have

ng-jwplayer directive to display players and,

```
<div>
  <uib-tabset justified="true" style="padding-top: 45px;" >
    <uib-tab heading="JWPlayer 6" select="changePlayer(jwp=7)"></uib-tab>
    <uib-tab heading="JWPlayer 7" select="changePlayer(jwp=6)"></uib-tab>
</uib-tabset>
```

bootstrap Tab, I want to switch between players, when I select the Tab.

I used $rootscope in player.controller.js and ng-if in index.html to use custom jwplayer6 or jwplayer7, but it didn't work.

Also I tried to import custom jwplayer scripts in player.html, it also didn't work.

Does anyone have any idea how to include and manage both jwplayer6 and jwplayer7 in same project?

Thanks

Comment: can i ask why you need to use both in the same project? certain feature sets you want to utilize i suppose? can you describe the use case in more detail? thanks!

Comment: everytime when jwplayer release new version, I want to monitor new version vs previous stable version. if there is any problems or not.

Comment: still, you should be able to have them in the same project with no issue. having them on the same page loaded simultaneously might be another story.

Answer (score 0):

I handled it using iframe. I keep player scripts in .ejs file and call them with an iframe in angular side. It works perfect.